# Comparing Of Two DataGridView And Delete Same Rows In C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, datatable, multiple-columns

I have 2 DataGridViews. After doing some operations in my first DataGridView, I transfer the rows ??to my second DataGridView. Now, I want to do this. In my second DataGridView, I don't want to add rows that are the same as the first DataGridView.

My DataGridView1 looks like that:

```
           Column 1                Column 2
       ---------------------------------------
           hello friends              250
           hi guys                    15
           good day                   15684
           old days                   156153
           bye bye                    6143
```

If my DataGridView2 looks like that;

```
           Column 1                Column 2
       ---------------------------------------
           new coders                 88
           hello friends              250
           january february           31
           such good                  1684
           play music                 1553
           bye bye                    6143
```

I don't want to see same rows in my DataGridView2 (from DataGridView1) and I don't want to add it. So my DataGridView2 should look like that;

```
           Column 1                Column 2
       ---------------------------------------
           new coders                 88
           january february           31
           such good                  1684
           play music                 1553
```

It's my code:

```
       connection.Open();
       string[] ss = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ');
       int css = ss.Count();
       for (int mi = 0; mi < css; mi++)
       {
           string mq = "SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM myTable WHERE c1='" + ss[mi] + "' OR c2='" + ss[mi] + "'";
           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(mq, connection);
           DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
           sd.Fill(dt1);
           foreach (DataRow r in dt1.Rows)
           {
               dgv1.Rows.Add(r["c1"].ToString() + " " + r["c2"].ToString(), r["c3"]);
           }
       }
       //Some insignificant operations.
       for (int mi2 = 0; mi2 < countOFMYNEWFORDGV1; mi2++)
       {
           string mySecondQuery= "SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM myTable WHERE c1='" + myNEWFORDGV1[mi2] + "' OR c2='" + myNEWFORDGV1[mi2] + "'";
           SqlDataAdapter secondDA= new SqlDataAdapter(mySecondQuery, conection);
           DataTable dtForSecond= new DataTable();
           secondDA.Fill(dtForSecond);
           foreach (DataRow mySecondRow in dtForSecond.Rows)
           {
               dgv2.Rows.Add(mySecondRow["c1"].ToString() + " " + mySecondRow["c2"].ToString(), mySecondRow["c3"]);                        
           }
       }
       con.Close();
```

Note 1: I edited my code.

Note 2: Please share your full answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: From your code it is clear that `ss` is a string array. Can you also share the datatype of `myNEWFORDGV1` ?

Comment: before second for loop you should do `myNEWFORDGV1 = myNEWFORDGV1.Except(ss).ToArray();`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya ss is a string array and myNEWFORDGV1 is string. Why should I do this?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have no problem in my code. I wanto to do only I mentioned.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I think I need a DataTable operation but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Thre is no problem in your code. It the logic you need to correct. 
I am not sure why you think `myNEWFORDGV1 ` is not a string array. The solution I suggested is about not to query duplicate data from the database at all. Instead of getting duplicate data in both the tables and removing them, I am suggesting to remove the duplicate items from the string array itself so that it will not retrieve duplicate data in the second datatable. Did you try doing `myNEWFORDGV1 = myNEWFORDGV1.Except(ss).ToArray();` before `for (int mi2 = 0; mi2 < countOFMYNEWFORDGV1; mi2++)` ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Sir I tried it but it didn't work. I think I need a if block in my foreach, or I need a new DataTable but I don't know how can I do it. I want to only check and if datagridview2 has same rows from datagridview1 then I don't want to add it to my datagridview2.

Comment: You can directly use a query with join to get the desired result. I added my solution, please review.

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? Are you getting any error? Are you getting some different behavior?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it returns unwanted values.

Comment: Can you share the contents of `ss` variable and `myNEWFORDGV1` variable. Also sample data from the dataTable? All these in the question itself.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Sir I share everything. I shared my code and my DataGridViews. My full code is about 500 rows. It's only a part. ss has single words and myNEWFORDGV1 has my DataGridView1's second words for each row.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I think you're looking for the error in wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through each row I would suggest to get the result in single query. By using left outer join we'll get all the results of DataGridView2 with common record of DataGridView1, then we'll filter out the required record by filter of null values.

```
GO

  ;with cte as (
    Select dg2.[Column 1] as c1, dg2.[Column 2] as c2, dg1.[Column 1] as dc1 
    from DataGridView2 as dg2 left outer join DataGridView1 as dg1 
    on dg2.[Column 1]=dg1.[Column 1] and dg2.[Column 2]=dg1.[Column 2] )
  select * from cte where dc1 is null

GO
```

You'll get your desired result from that query only for above given table structure.

If any confusion then ping me for same.

Comment: Where should I add this code? I don't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by one of following two ways.

1. Retrieve data in both the datatables and remove duplicate rows in C# code.
2. Do not retrieve the duplicate rows from the database itself.

Following is the sample code I have written to solve the problem same as yours using approach 2 listed above.

The actual data in the table and in the variables are assumed based on the code shared by you.

To start with there is table 'myTable' in database with following data.

```
   c1   |     c2    | c3   
----------------------------
 hello  |  friends  | 250
 hi     |  guys     | 15
 good   |  day      | 15684
 old    |  days     | 156153
 bye    |  bye      | 6143
 new    |  coders   | 88
 january|  february | 31
 such   |  good     | 1684
 play   |  music    | 1553
```

Following is the code written the remove the duplicate rows while showing data in the GridView2.

```
var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=<<dbserver>>; Initial Catalog=<<dbname>>;uid=<<uid>>;password=<<password>>");

var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

var str = "'" + string.Join("','", ss) + "'";

// Instead of looping thru all the items of ss to query the database again and again
// I am using IN query to query the database in one opration.
string sqlstmt = "SELECT * FROM myTable where c1 IN (" + str + ") or c2 IN (" + str +")";
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

sqlConnection.Open();
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlstmt, sqlConnection);
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
sqlConnection.Close();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];

//With above code GridView1 displayed data a following.
   c1   |     c2    | c3   
----------------------------
 hello  |  friends  | 250
 hi     |  guys     | 15
 good   |  day      | 15684
 old    |  days     | 156153
 bye    |  bye      | 6143

// With following line of code I am trying to remove duplicate query parameters.
// I am doing this because Same SELECT statement is being used 
// to query the data for both GridView1 and GridView2.
// Only the parameter value changes.
myNEWFORDGV1 = myNEWFORDGV1.Except(ss).ToArray();

str = "'" + string.Join("','", myNEWFORDGV1) + "'";

string query = "SELECT * FROM myTable where c1 IN (" + str + ") or c2 IN (" + str + ")";
dataSet = new DataSet();
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConnection);
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
sqlConnection.Close();
dataGridView2.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];

GridView2 will display following data now.
   c1   |     c2    | c3   
----------------------------
 new    |  coders   | 88
 january|  february | 31
 such   |  good     | 1684
 play   |  music    | 1553
```

Try and understand the logic of this code and apply it your use case. This should resolve your issue of having duplicate rows.

Comment: I'm so new at this job. Sometimes I don't understand the complex structures, because I'm new as i said. I will try it, thank you for your answer and thank you for wasting your time. I thought I needed something like this, but it didn't work;


DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
List<string> table2Column1 = dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Column 1")).ToList();
DataTable dt3 = dt1.AsEnumerable().Where(x => table2Column1.IndexOf(x.Field<string>("Column 1")) >= 0).CopyToDataTable();